# Uninstalling IntelliJ Idea from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, intellij

I want to know a step by step solution to uninstall it using terminal commands.

Answer (score 3):

It will depend on the version of IntelliJ Idea you have.
IntelliJ suggests to use commands

```
umake -r ide idea
```

or

```
umake -r ide idea-ultimate
```

If you get the message

> Command 'umake' not found, but can be installed with:
>
> sudo snap install ubuntu-make  # version master, or
>   sudo apt  install ubuntu-make
>
> See 'snap info ubuntu-make' for additional versions.

and after installing and using the umake command again you obtain

> ERROR: You can't remove Idea Ultimate as it isn't installed

you will have to proceed manually, (Remove the whole Idea directory where the bin/idea.sh file is)
If you are not in the mood to install more stuff, this other command might work

```
sudo apt-get remove idea
```

you can find the name of your app by using this command

```
apt list --installed
```

If (like in my case) there is not any IntelliJ or Idea item on the installed-software list, 
you will have to proceed manually, (Remove the whole Idea directory where the bin/idea.sh file is)

There are other tutorials to remove Idea completely. After deleting the folder with IDE installation, remove IDE settings/caches directories, should be enough.

Answer (score 3):

If you had installed Intellij-Idea using `snap`, than do [the next](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/uninstall.html?section=Linux):

1. `sudo rm -fr ~/.IdeaIC*/config && sudo rm -fr ~/.IdeaIC*/system`
2. `sudo snap remove intellij-idea-community --purge` or `sudo snap remove intellij-idea-ultimate --purge`
3. `sudo find * / | grep snap | grep intellij-idea` will show what you additionally could remove:

   ```
   $ sudo rm -fr /var/lib/snapd/sequence/intellij-idea-community.json
   ```
4. If you want to remove downloaded package of Idea, then also clear cache from root user: `# rm -fr /var/lib/snapd/cache/*`. `sudo` could not help.

Comment: Can i ask: how to you figure out a very complex process above ?